# Is it possible in Retrofit to use Form Encoded and Multipart in single request

Tags: android

Here is my sample code.

@Multipart

```
@POST("/upload-end-users-document")
Call<ListPinDevicesResponse<UploadEndUsersDocumentResponse>> getUploadEndUsersDocument(@PartMap Map<String, String> userParams,@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params,@Header("access-token") String accessToken);
```

- is there a no way to use @Field and @part together in Retrofit??
- If yes than tell a reason, If no tell me a proper way

I will appreciate your answer and thank you in advance.

Screenshots of Postman tool is attached in the link below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J-MkO49gfXpYKwxyBqtzHqotnCgHJ9yp/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d1WZPHVSxFsvyY4zvXVmd9OBYcsSn3yG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try to update your question to be more clear

Comment: We are trying to use multipart with encoded data by using retrofit. can we use (@PartMap Map<String, String> in multipart. If yes then tell us how ? Thanks in advance